# Get data from Crystal Report (.rpt)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, crystal-reports

What is the best way to get data from a saved Crystal Report file (.rpt)?  I have only the .rpt file and no access to the data source.

One way is to export the Report file to XML and work with that (this I have already tested, and it works pretty good).

Is there a way to directly work with the Report file and access the content?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Crystal Report Component Lib/SDK.  I have used it to provide integration with a web app, but I havn't tried to read data from a .rpt file with it, so not sure if it support this, I would hope so.

Try here: http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp

Comment: It doesn't seem to have support for Visual Studio 2010